# Spring Cloud RestTemplate add auth token

Tags: spring, spring-security, netflix-zuul

How to correctly implement restTemplate with authorisation token?

I have a Zuul gateway which passes a JWT downstream  to other services correctly, assuming I don't want to do anything on the gateway first, using a config like:

```
zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  routes:
    instance-service:
      path: /instances/**
      strip-prefix: false
```

And using a token relay filter:

```
@Component
public class TokenRelayFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        Set<String> headers = (Set<String>) ctx.get("ignoredHeaders");
        headers.remove("authorization");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10000;
    }
}
```

Which just forwards everything to the instance-service, works a treat.

However if I remove the `routes` config from the config.yml file because I want to handle some things on the gateway before manually calling the service I loose the access token and get a 401 back from the downstream services

```
@ApiOperation(value = "List all instances and their properties.")
@GetMapping("/instances")
public ResponseEntity<String> instances() {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<String> reference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {
    };

    return restTemplate.exchange("http://instance-service", HttpMethod.GET, null, reference);
}
```

My `RestTemplate` is just wired up generically

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

How do I correctly get the JWT back into the new RestTemplate without having to manually create and add a header in each request?

Am I supposed to be using `OAuth2RestTemplate`?

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this a bit - it sounds like you trying to host a REST endpoint within your Zuul router that is not subject to the proxy. This endpoint is supposed to reach out to downstream services, but is missing some kind of authorization header that those services (not zuul) require, resulting in a 401 from the downstream service. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, the rest endpoint is there to pretty much establish CQRS, sending `POST` requests to a message queue, and `GET` requests to the correct services.

Comment: And you are looking to autoconfigure your RestTemplate in Zuul to automatically detect the auth header that came in with the initial request, and re-use it, similar to what the proxy is doing?

Comment: Yup correct again!

Comment: So for the RestTemplate, since we're actually dealing with two requests(one inbound to Zuul, and another outbound to your service), I'm not sure if there would be a better way aside from scraping the auth header out of the request to Zuul via @RequestHeader and just adding it on to the new outbound request manually. I'm curious why this couldn't be part of the proxy though. If we have to forward requests to the downstream service anyways, couldn't this live in a pre filter?

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer... as that was all I could think of too however I'm very new to Spring in general. Perhaps it could be a pre filter? Is this not a common design pattern in Spring land? I just assume this would have been done a million times and have a proper spring-way to handle it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159956/discussion-between-nick-defazio-and-peavers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion, it seems like you have two options:

1. Implement and endpoint and dig the Auth header out via `@RequestParam` on request. From there, you can add it back on for the subsequent outbound request via `RestTemplate` to your downstream service.
2. Use Zuul to proxy your request (Auth header included, make sure its excluded from the `sensitive-headers` config) and implement a pre filter to include any additional logic you might need.

If I had to pick, it sounds like something Zuul should be doing since it's likely acting as your gateway for both your queue and other services, and it looks like you are trying to implement a proxy request, which Zuul can already do, but it's tough to say without knowing the full scope of the architecture.